# Why do we need session service of NetBIOS over TCP IP?

Tags: tcp

While reading on NetBIOS from https://wiki.wireshark.org/NetBIOS  , they tell that NetBIOS provides session service:**"it's a service providing reliable, in-order delivery of packets"**

Doesn't TCP already provide us both in-order and reliable delivery of packets?

Looks like NetBIOS used to work only in LAN, using TCP/IP it can be used in the internet now, they could have removed the **"session service"** capabilities of NetBIOS when implemented over TCP/IP right?

Is it only because of **"backward compatibility"** stupid logic we have this?

Its simply looks like a lot of bloat ware to me.

Comment: Questions about protocols above OSI layer 4 are off topic here. You can possibly ask this on [su].

Comment: "above layer 4", not "including layer 4". TCP questions are on topic here, NetBIOS related questions aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :) :
It is the backward compatibility requirement:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1001

Page 7  "4.1.  PRESERVE NetBIOS SERVICES" was one of the design principles.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as answered, so this doesn't keep popping up - well done!